# Run Python script importing xmlrpclib on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, xmlrpclib

I have been using Linux to programm Python scripts, but now I have to make one of them work on Windows XP, and here I am a beginner. I have installed Python 3.4 in C:\Python34, and I have my Python script in E:\solidworks_xmlrpc. This script works perfectly on Linux, but on Windows I get this error message:

```
import xmlrpclib
ImportError: No module named "xmlrpclib"
```

I checked if there was an xmlrpc folder in C:\Python34\Lib and there is. I also defined PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME in system variables.

Anyone knows how to solve this, please?

Thank you so much.

**EDIT**

I deleted the content of the programm only a moment to proof:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

And the cmd returned this:

```
['E:\\solidworks_xmlrpc', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Python34\\
DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: can you please update answer with this, "import sys print sys.path"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the real answer to the question:

Python 3.4 brings the library xmlrpc, which replaces old xmlrpclib.

So, if you have installed Python 3.4 on Windows and you want to use xmlrpclib (probably as a client side), don't write anymore this:

```
import xmlrpclib
```

Replace that with this line:

```
from xmlrpc import client
```

And replace every match of *xmlrpc* in the rest of your code with *client*.