# xmlrpclib error 'module not found' when trying to access gandi api

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, xml-rpc

I am trying to set the DS record in the gandi api as describded in the [gandi api support doc](http://doc.rpc.gandi.net/domain/reference.html?highlight=dnssec#DomainDnssecOperationReturn)

It states to 'import xmlrpclib' but I immediately get an error 'module not found' (full text reproduced below).

I [found this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528530/run-python-script-importing-xmlrpclib-on-windows) where they use 'from xmlrpc import client', but in my context, the gandi API is none responsive.

python3 session:

```
>>> import xmlrpclib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#69>", line 1, in <module>
    import xmlrpclib
ImportError: No module named 'xmlrpclib'
>>> from xmlrpc import client
>>> api = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#71>", line 1, in <module>
    api = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
NameError: name 'xmlrpclib' is not defined
>>> api = xmlclient.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#72>", line 1, in <module>
    api = xmlclient.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
NameError: name 'xmlclient' is not defined
>>> api = client.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
>>> apikey = '<my_api_key_here>'
>>> version = api.version.info(apikey)
>>> print(version)
{'api_version': '3.3.29'}
>>> domain.dnssec.create('KEY', 'domain2.com', 1, 256, 'KEY')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    domain.dnssec.create('KEY', 'domain2.com', 1, 256, 'KEY')
NameError: name 'domain' is not defined
>>> client.dnssec.create('KEY', 'domain2.com', 1, 256, 'KEY')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    client.dnssec.create('KEY', 'domain2.com', 1, 256, 'KEY')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dnssec'
```

How do I update the DS record via gandi API?

Update:
The following code was provided to me and errors with an invalid key error.
The key I am using is known good in PhP

```
my_in_file = open('/home/ex-mailer-domains/'+domain+'/dsset-'+domain+'.', 'rt')
dstext = my_in_file.read()
dslist = dstext.split()[3:7]
print(dslist[3])

api = client.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
apikey = 'MyKeyThatWorksInPHPjustFineForOtherScripts'
api.domain.dnssec.create(apikey, 'domain2.com', {'algorithm': 8, 'flags': 256, 'public_key': dslist[3]})





xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 510150: 'Error on object : OBJECT_ACCOUNT (CAUSE_NORIGHT) [Invalid API key]'>
```

UPDATE:
The key works for this sample code

But using it with other calls, I still get the error:

```
>>> api = client.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
>>> apikey = 'MyKeyThatWorksInPHPjustFineForOtherScripts'
>>> version = api.version.info(apikey)
>>> print(version)
{'api_version': '3.3.29'}
>>> domain.dnssec.create('xxxxx', 'domain2.com', 1, 256, '97BF8186C193EBF12A794A75FEF4B331A29C1A26')
```

Comment: You are trying to use variables that are not initialized. Perhaps you should read the Python tutorial.

Comment: You might look at the big note under the python example you are probably trying to copy from the docs - http://doc.rpc.gandi.net/overview.html#xml-rpc-interface  The example given is for Python 2 - you are trying to use Python 3 so need to use the second form as per [Antti's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30815475/838992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you did give out your real API key, but I urge you to change it ASAP. In any case, in Python, top level variables/names do not come from thin air - they're introduced either by `import` or the assignment statement (`x = 123`), (or some other statements like `def`, `class` usually).

You never assigned anything into `domain` variable, then it couldn't possibly work; the same goes for `xmlrpclib`; since the `import` statement failed, the name is not defined.

Thus how about:

```
>>> from xmlrpc import client
>>> api = client.ServerProxy('https://rpc.gandi.net/xmlrpc/')
>>> apikey = '123'
>>> api.domain.dnssec.create(apikey, 'domain2.com', {'algorithm': 42, 
                             'flags': 123, 'public_key': 'foobarbaz'})
```

Comment: I am getting an invalid key error. The key I am using works fine for PhP scripts   http://paste.ee/p/VJDnm

Answer (score 1):

The xmlrpclib module has been renamed to xmlrpc.client in Python 3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.